# GUI app stops when starting socket server

Tags: python-3.x

My project is with thinner if I start socket server then the program stops.

I have Tkinter project, if I start the class the program stop and hangs.

```
class msyslog:
    def __init__(self):
        HOST, PORT = "10.0.1.18", 514

        global table_name
        global db_name
        global db_host
        global db_user
        global db_password

        db_name = 'logging'
        table_name = 'logs'
        db_user = 'root'
        db_password = ''
        db_host = '127.0.0.1'
        db_port = 3306

        try:
            # mysql_connection=mysql.connector.connect(user =db_user, password =db_password, host = db_host, port = db_port)
            mysql_connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_password)
        except mysql.connector.custom_error_exception():
            print('Error:')

        cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
        create_db(db_name, cursor)

        cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
        create_table(db_name, table_name, cursor)

        mysql_connection.commit()

        mysql_connection.close()


        server = socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), SyslogUDPHandler)
        server.db_name = db_name
        server.table_name = table_name
        server.db_user = db_user
        server.db_password = db_password
        server.db_host = db_host
        server.db_port = db_port

        server.serve_forever()
```

How can I make the server work in the background and my GUI project work as the interface.

Answer (score -1):

### Problem

Tkinter stops because Python is busy with serving the server forever. What you are doing is saying tkinter to start. Tkinter has is own loop (mainloop function), which needs to run freely when using you're GUI, so tkinter can add widgets, destory them, edit them, et certera. In the meantime, you said to your MySQL client to serve the server forever, thus preventing the mainloop from looping freely. The mainloop waits until the function you called using, for example, a button, is done. However, you said to serve forever so that won't ever be.

### Solution

Make a thread from your class. Namely, multiple threads can do stuff at the same time.

Import threading and make this statement in your Python code.

```
threading.Thread(target=YourFunction, args=(arg1, arg2)).start()
```

This wil let the thread, and thus your class, know to start. You can use the target to call a function or call your class directly with, class.__init__. It is important that you don't use parantheses. The args argument is optional. You can read more about threading in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), or just ask me.

Sincerly, Chris Fowl